# Gate-level implementation of Eigenvalue-Inversion in HHL

Tags: gate-synthesis, hhl-algorithm

I am trying to understand how does the gate-level implementation of eigenvalue-inversion step in the HHL algorithm works.

I am following this [reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.08227.pdf), where it is stated (Lemma 4) that this can be accomplished by the use of controlled rotations:

$$ U_\theta: |\widetilde{\theta} \rangle |0 \rangle \rightarrow |\widetilde{\theta} \rangle \left(\cos \widetilde{\theta} |0\rangle + sin \widetilde{\theta} |1 \rangle \right ) $$

$$U_\theta = \sum_{\widetilde{\theta} \in \{0,1\}^n} |\widetilde{\theta}\rangle \langle \widetilde{\theta}| \otimes \exp \left(-i \widetilde{\theta} \sigma_y \right) $$

where $\widetilde{\theta}$ is the n-bit finite precision representation of the angle $\theta$, and $\sigma_y$ the Y Pauli matrix.

My question is, how are the rotation angles $\widetilde{\theta}$ for the unitary $U_\theta$ calculated/applied without a-priori knowledge of the eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ of the system matrix $A$?

I understand that the state-vector $|\widetilde{\theta} \rangle$ is obtained in the previous step of the algorithm by extracting the eigenvalues $|\lambda_j \rangle$ of $A$ using QPE (and then applying an inverse + arcsin function as described [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15070/how-to-effectively-compute-eigenvalue-rotation-in-hhl)), but I am not sure how are these angles also applied as the parameters for the controlled-rotation gates (exponent parameter in $U_\theta$.)

FYI, I did see this other [post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11422/problem-with-controlled-rotation-in-hhl) where it is stated: "You... ...have (at least a good approximation to) your eigenvalues recorded on a register. If you control off that register, you can use it to decide the angle of the rotation for each eigenvector."

So my question is *how* do you "use it [the register containing $|\widetilde{\theta} \rangle$] to decide the angle of the rotation [$\widetilde{\theta}$ in the $\exp$ function of $U_\theta$]"?

Thanks!

Comment: Nice question. If there's no answers after a while you can ping me and I can try my best to make time to write you an answer.

Comment: Thank you @user1271772, with some help, I have actually identified a way to implement this, but I would appreciate if you could let me know if this is what you had in mind. For theta in [0,2*pi):
Each qubit theta_k (of the n-bit representation of theta) is used as the control of an CRx(alpha_k) gate acting on an ancilla qubit. The angle applied alpha_k is given by (2*pi/2^n)*2^k

Comment: You do have an answer now, thankfully :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the register to decide the angle of rotation means the following: you have a register $|\tilde{\theta}\rangle$ (composed of potentially more than one qubit) and you apply rotations of another register controlled on the value of the qubits of $|\tilde{\theta}\rangle$. Different rotations that you apply result in different functions being implemented on your ancilla qubits. But that was possibly already known to you.

The question of *which rotations to do for applying a specific function* is much more complicated, and I am not aware of any general solution. For once, [Qiskit](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aqua/blob/master/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/linear_solvers/hhl.py) has its own implementation of HHL, but I don't know up to which point it is general. There are however, other examples in which it is "easy" to implement, for instance, the eigenvalue inversion function required for HHL. In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.11463), the authors implement an approximation of the eigenvalue inversion subroutine (the code in `Quil` can be found in [the associated GitLab repository](https://gitlab.com/apozas/bayesian-dl-quantum/-/blob/master/HHL_Rigetti.py#L168)) that is exact in the case of eigenvalues that are powers of 2. The reason why it is exact for powers of 2 is because in that case the inversion can be written as a combination of bit swaps, so the eigenvalue inversion subroutine is a collection of controlled SWAP gates (a pictorial representation of the circuit is in Fig. 3 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2485)). But, as I said before, I am not aware of general ways of implementing large classes of functions, so far.

Comment: What’s wrong with what’s proposed [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15070/how-to-effectively-compute-eigenvalue-rotation-in-hhl)

Comment: The problem is in the first step of the two in the question you refer to. The second part maps a bit string into an amplitude, and that is fairly easy done with controlled Ry gates. The problem still lies in the first step, the one that (roughly) maps a register encoding $\lambda$ to a register encoding $1/\lambda$. From the answer to the question it is possible that IBM has figured out a way to do so, but it is by no means a simple thing to do.